# Using Form1.TextBox1.Text as Value for MySQL Select Command in Form2

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, forms, onload

I have TextBox1.Text and Button1 on Form1.
I click the Button1 that ShowDialog() on Form2.
The OnLoad Form2 get data from a mysql database and show that data in a DataGridView1.

In the MySQL command i need that the Form1.TextBox1.Text is a Value

Like this

```
"SELECT id FROM tablename WHERE id ='" & Form1.TextBox1.Text & "'"
```

Someone can help me?

---

**SOLVED**

**Solution:**

in **Form2 Public Class**

```
Dim Text1 As String
Dim Text2 As String 'if you need to transfer multiple values

Public Sub New(ByVal Textbox1 As String, ByVal Textbox2 As String)

    InitializeComponent()
    Me.Text1 = Textbox1 
    Me.Text2 = Textbox2 

End Sub
```

in **Form1 Button1 Click**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object,
              ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim Frm2 As New Form2(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text)
        Me.Hide()
        Frm2.ShowDialog()
        Me.Show()

    End Sub
```

Comment: By the way, never use text concatenation to build SQL queries!

Comment: Don't do that; it causes this: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=vtech+hack - please read http://bobby-tables.com and never again write an SQL like that

Comment: @AndyA. If i set Form1.TextBox1 disabled and not visible, could problems appear?

Comment: Form2 will need to have some form of reference to the INSTANCE of Form1 so it can access the TextBox.  Then the textbox may need access modifers updated to allow it to be accessable by form2.  Much cleaner option is to pass the value of TextBox1 into Form2, maybe in the constructor.

Comment: @ClaudioLiverano - doesn't matter if it could appear, never ever do this!

Comment: @Hursey I solved it with your advice. I used constructors to transfer data from one form to another.

Comment: It's good practice to use `AddWithValue` or `Add` instead of concatenating an input string into a sql command.